# Maximize $ax + by + c$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, economics

Working on a problem of comparative advantage of the economist David Ricardo, I've gone into solving a more general case of that study in which I stumbled over this question : how do we maximize the quantity $P = ax + by + c$, given that $a, b$ and $c$ are all known and $x, y$ are variables confined to the interval $[ 0,T] $.

---

In short, my query is : Determine $(x,y) \in [0,T]^2$ such that $(ax + by + c)$ is maximal, with $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, all of which are known.

Thank you !

Comment: This is the same as solving $c+\max_{x \in [0,T]} ax + \max_{y \in [0,T]} by = c+\max(aT,0) + \max(bT,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $a, b \neq 0$, use these four statements to get the maximum:

If $a$ is negative, $x=0$.

If $a$ is positive, $x=T$.

If $b$ is negative, $y=0$.

If $b$ is positive, $y=T$.

*"Do. Or do not. There is no try."  ~Yoda*

Comment: Oh, I feel bad missing that, I went by the general mode of thinking were $x, y$ are in $\mathbb{R}$, a case where I think your thinking process still holds. *"Do. Or do not. There is no try." ~Yoda*, dude, explain this phrase I am curious !